# Choosing SVG or CSS3 for gradients

Tags: css, svg

I would like to use gradients heavily in a new website I'm working on. I've been wondering if it would be better to implement the gradients in CSS3 or SVG.

Typically I only need multi-stop linear gradients so both meet my needs there.

I initially assumed this was best done in CSS3, but started to question my decision and would appreciate other opinions.

**My thinking thus far is that SVG (as a CSS background) may be better because:**

- It works in IE9
- My CSS is cleaner w/o browser prefixes
- Easy reuse of gradient

**CSS3 may be better because:**

- Seems like a job for CSS
- Less downloads for the client
- Everything is in one place

An important consideration that I don't know the answer to is which performs better?

Is there a best practice for implementing background gradients?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to a test performed by Lea Verou (I trust her work), CSS gradients are faster:
http://lea.verou.me/2011/08/css-gradients-are-much-faster-than-svg/

**UPDATE:**

You could also consider using modernizr to serve up SVG to IE9 which supports SVG backgrounds but does not support CSS gradients.

In your CSS you would just do:

```
.cssgradients #someElement { /* Gradient background rule. */ }
.no-cssgradients #someElement { /* SVG background rule. */ }
```

More info here:

http://modernizr.com

Answer (score 3):

Don't make your design choices based on making IE happy. Use progressive enhancement / graded browser support and push IE to the bottom of your support list.

Choose CSS3: your website will just appear without gradients on IE, which is probably an acceptable compromise to make.

Answer (score 3):

You should use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to generate CSS and SVG (for IE9) both.

Example :

```
background: #fefcea; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fefcea 0%, #f1da36 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fefcea), color-stop(100%,#f1da36)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fefcea 0%,#f1da36 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fefcea 0%,#f1da36 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fefcea 0%,#f1da36 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #fefcea 0%,#f1da36 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefcea', endColorstr='#f1da36',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

It automatically generate IE9 svg code

> Support for full multi-stop gradients with IE9 (using SVG). Add a
>   "gradient" class to all your elements that have a gradient, and add
>   the following override to your HTML to complete the IE9 support:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question the OP is asking.  It's great that one is able to support both with minimal code— but the OP is asking for advantages and disadvantages.  The only way this answer makes sense is if it were prefixed with _“both gradients are completely equivalent in every way; different browsers just support different gradient types”_, which wouldn't be a factual statement.

Answer (score 1):

I have chosen to implement my linear gradients in svg as I can do it once, I am of course only supporting modern browsers.

This is the SVG, I only need to describe it once. I am not sure if there is a way to define the x1y1 and x2 y2 co-ordinates using css. happy to be proven wrong.

So if CSS can not implement a gradient with x1y1 x2y2 co-ordinates I guess this is an advantage of using svg linear gradients.

the following code can be taken straight of out inkscape.

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"     viewBox="0 0 200 200">

    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="26.3" y1="0.2" x2="26.5" y2="3.9" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
         <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#0284a4;stop-opacity:0.9" />
         <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#0284a5;stop-opacity:1" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
  <path id="skylevel10" fill="url(#grad1)" d="m 0 -0 201 0 0 6.7 c 0 0 -29.8 1.2  Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: why can't you define the gradients only once in CSS?